# In Excel is there a keyboard shortcut for jumping back to the last cell edited?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I find myself in Excel a lot editing a cell and then jumping to some other part of the spreadsheet so I can find some information and then scroll all the way back to the cell I was editing.  This wastes alot of time. Is it possible to edit a cell, scroll or find what I am looking for far away, maybe copy it, and then return back to the cell I was editing originally using a shortcut key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such shortcut is built-in.

It sounds like you may benefit from either Excel's split window mode, or its ability to have multiple windows open of the same workbook.

Split mode lets you divide the current window into two or four separately scrollable panes. Turn it on by choosing **Split** on the View tab of the ribbon.

Alternatively you can open a second window of your workbook which can be used to work with a different area of your worksheet. Add another Windows by choosing **New Window** on the View tab.

Comment: But that's so slow...I need it to be something faster, like a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @leeand00 have you tried it? Done this way, you can look at the other information you need to review without leaving the cell you're editing!

Comment: I actually tried it yesterday and yes it works as well as you stated provided you open a seperate view use ALT+W, W, and then the sheet you want to switch to.  Unfortunately, where I work we aren't allowed to split the view directly on the spreadsheet for some reason;  I don't know why either.